# OrderedDictionary breaking change in .NET 4?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

A coworker of mine came across this the other day while we were working on upgrading a project to .NET 4.

Given the following code:

```
 var od = new System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary();

 od.Add("key1", "value1");
 od.Add("key2", "value2");

 foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in od)
 {
     od[entry.Key] = null;
 }
```

In .NET 3.5, setting an entry to null will work fine. As expected, the key would still be in the dictionary, and its matching value would be null.

In .NET 4.0, this throws an InvalidOperationException saying

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I thought maybe there was a change to OrderedDictionary where setting an entry to null would remove it entirely, but doing a quick test says the entry is still there when you set it to null.

Is this a breaking change that has gone unreported?

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't with trying to change the entry from within a `foreach` loop, rather than simply setting it to `null`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From *[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary)*:

> The `foreach` statement is a wrapper around the enumerator, which only allows reading from, not writing to, the collection.

I believe it means that you were using it incorrectly, and it is your fault that you were using it in this way. It wasn't supposed to be working, and it doesn't work now.

Comment: Thanks for this(and everyone else who answered). I can't believe I overlooked that in the documentation!

Answer (score 7):

You have found a breaking change. In previous versions of `OrderedDictionary`, the internal `OrderedDictionaryEnumerator` class used array indexes in order to traverse the array. As long as items weren't *removed* or *added*, it wouldn't complain.

The new version uses the underlying enumerator that the array itself returns through `GetEnumerator`, and that's why you're seeing the code fail.

That being said, it's only a breaking change *that should never have worked to begin with*. It's entirely illegal to modify--in any way--a collection over which you're enumerating, whether it's through a `foreach` loop or using the `IEnumerator` explicitly. What you found was a bug that was fixed.

Comment: Notwithstanding the way enumeration is documented, there is a longstanding tradition that an enumerator is allowed to remain functional when the source collection is modified provided it behaves sensibly.  Something like the enumerator on `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` would be pretty useless without such an ability.

Answer (score 4):

It is a bug fix.  The feedback article that triggered the fix [is here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/384059/ordereddictionary-enumerator-doesnt-throw-invalidoperationexception-after-collection-was-changed).

Comment: That is, it was *fixed* in .NET 4.0 (I had to read the post three times to understand it :-)

Comment: The link is broken - it redirects to a generic page, *"Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired"*.

Comment: Not much I can do about it.  Nothing changed in the past 8 years, it was still a bug fix in .NET 4.0 that was instigated by a bug report.  Notably, .NET 4.0 fumbled a similar check in [List<>.ForEach()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,545), fixed again in 4.5 but now with a more pressing need to be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with null. It has everything to do with the fact that you are modifying the collection in a `foreach` loop. Doing so invalidates the iterator and breaks the enumeration process.

You can safely set the value to null (for nullable value types, that is), *outside* of the foreach.

That is, this will work:

```
od.Add("key2", null);
```